# How can I change the area of an image that "object-fit: cover" shows/hides

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image which I used the CSS property of "object-fit: cover" on but the focus of the image is cropped. Is there anyway to fix this in CSS?

image ex.

(the "0" is the focus/part that I want in frame)

```
+-------------------------+
|-------------------------|
|-------------------------|
|-------------------------|
+------------0------------+
```

I am unsure what to try and I haven't found any info yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) property that you can set along `object-fit`.